# Tarjan's offline Least Common Ancestor Algorithm

Tags: data-structures

I am currently reading about an algorithm from Tarjan on how to get the Least Common Ancestor of two nodes in a Binary Tree.

I have read the pseudo code from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm), but I'm not getting the gist of it. I mean I am not able to apply the algorithm on any given Binary Tree. I also tried to find some explanation of each steps on Google but i did not get anything worth. So, if anybody can help me in understanding how this algorithm works on a Binary Tree, it would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the given binary tree , you should implement another data structure named disjoint set to apply this algorithm . There are three main methods along with this data structure , MAKE-SET、UNION、FIND-SET . I strongly recommend you to read Chapter 21 "Data Structures for Disjoint Sets" of 《Introduction to algorithms》 for a better understanding.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all. Even after knowing how those work, it's still non-obvious that Tarjan's algorithm works.